# CKEDITOR 4: remain editor height when toggling toolbar

Tags: javascript, html, toolbar, ckeditor4.x

I use the classic version of ckeditor 4. The system I'm working with is a self-written CMS. That means I've got multiple cases where I need the ckeditor. Some of them are having the resizing-option/plugin enabled. In addition, most of them have an enabled toolbar.

When I resize the editor, the height of it changes (of course :D). In this case, it is intentional by the user. But when I toggle the toolbar, the height changes a lot, which is not intentional or wanted by the user.

Is there a possibility to let the editor remain its resized height when expanding or collapsing the toolbar? In the end, the editor in total should remain at the same height, no matter if the toolbar is expanded or collapsed.

Hope I described my problem comprehensibly :)

[Collapsed: 280px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxLyH.png)
[Expanded: 329px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4QbA.png)

Both states should have 280px

Answer (score 0):

Store the height just before collapsing or expanding the toolbar and reapply it afterwards. For a CKEditor instance called `editor1`:

```
let ckHeight;

CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on('beforeCommandExec', function(evt) {
    if (evt.data.name == 'toolbarCollapse') {
        ckHeight = evt.editor.container.$.offsetHeight;
    }
});

CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on('afterCommandExec', function(evt) {
    if (evt.data.name == 'toolbarCollapse') {
        evt.editor.resize(evt.editor.container.$.offsetWidth, ckHeight);
    }
});
```